# H.264 Encoder and Decoder in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, h.264

In our iOS Application, we need to capture buffer from iPhone or iPad Camera and encode it using h.264 send it to server, 
Similarly device will receive h.264 it needs to be decode to raw RGB format and display it on the screen,

I want to know how to start with it, after googling it seems, iOS Doesn't have support for it, and we need to write custom H.264 Encoder and Decoder,

I will be getting streaming content

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html

> The export will not scale the video up from a smaller size. Video is compressed using H.264; audio is compressed using AAC. Some devices cannot support some sizes.